# Complicated sentences in past perfect regarding hypothetical situations with reflection on the past?

Tags: grammaticality, conditional-constructions, progressive-aspect, perfect-constructions

*Would have had to have been doing*, e.g.:

> For him to have become a threat in the teachers eyes, he **would have had to have been exhibiting** severely bad behavior all the time.

*Would have had to be doing*, e.g.:

> If I hadn't finished my work at school, I **would have had to be doing** it at home, whilst everyone else could have been doing something fun.

Are these grammatically correct despite being so clumsy?
Keeping in mind that in both sentences there should be maintained a sense of progression. So it is an ongoing action.

Comment: Yes,  they are grammatical despite being so clumsy.

Comment: These sentences are grammatically correct, but not natural. In both cases it would be more natural to use a simple infinitive instead: **to exhibit** rather than **to have been exhibiting** and **to do** rather than **to be doing**.   Other parts of the sentences are not natural either, for example **severely bad** rather than **extremely bad**. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=severely+bad%2C+extremely+bad.&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseverely%20bad%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cextremely%20bad%20.%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 4):

Grammar is like water, in that speakers will take the path of least resistance. Things begin to become ungrammatical, or at the very least unidiomatic, when the water starts flowing upstream, as it does in your examples.

I suspect most native speakers would use **must** there, to avoid **would have had to have been**:

> For him to have become a threat in the teacher's eyes, he **must** have
>   been exhibiting severely bad behavior.

That's not possible in the second example. My AmE ear tells me to avoid "would have had to **be doing**" and to say something like this instead:

> If I hadn't finished my work at school, I would have had to **continue
>   working** on it at home, while...."

or simply, **would have had to finish it at home**, as the semantics of the sentence don't demand the continuous.

Maybe something like this:

> If I hadn't reached him before he left the office to discuss that
>   emergency, I **would have had to be phoning** him repeatedly until he
>   answered the call on his mobile phone.

But even then, many native speakers would find **would have had to *phone* him repeatedly** sufficient.  As long as there's some indication of repetition, such as "repeatedly" or "again and again", it isn't necessary to use the continuous tense. Absent the adverbs, then **would have had to be phoning him until...** is more viable.